# Fixtures in Django testing with South / Selenium

Tags: django, unit-testing, selenium, django-south, django-fixtures

I am trying to run Selenium tests on a Django project (1.5.4), which uses South. I think South is conflicting with my tests when I try to inject initial data with fixtures, but I'm not sure why; I appreciate any help.

According to the Django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/overview/#topics-testing-fixtures), fixtures are supposed to be loaded after the first syncdb and then all migrations are applied.

Question 1) Does this take into account South migrations?? Do I need to run those separately somehow?

The error I get when I run my tests makes it seem like my South migrations are still present in the test database after the first test...but I thought each test has its own database (and migrations / fixtures) created? The first test passes / fails, but each subsequent test raises this IntegrityError:

```
IntegrityError: Problem installing fixture '<PROJECT_PATH>/fixtures/toy_course.json': Could not load contenttypes.ContentType(pk=8): (1062, "Duplicate entry 'south-migrationhistory' for key 'app_label'")
```

This [South documentation](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fixtures.html#initial-data) and [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13825216/how-to-load-fixtures-in-django-south-migrations-properly) seem to indicate that I need to override some type of **forwards** method in order to get fixtures working, but I'm not entirely sure how to apply that to a testing situation instead of production (or if that is the solution I need).

Question 2) Am I supposed to override **forwards** in my test setup? Where would I do it?

My relevant test code:

```
from django.conf import settings

from selenium import webdriver

from functional_tests.test import SeleniumTestCase

class Resources(SeleniumTestCase):
    fixtures = ['toy_course.json']

    def setUp(self):      
        self.browser = webdriver.Chrome(settings.SELENIUM_WEBDRIVER)
        self.browser.implicitly_wait(3)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.browser.quit()

    def test_main_page_renders_correctly(self):
        """
        User sees a properly formatted main page
        """
        self.open('/RDB/')

        h3_headers = self.browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('h3')
        self.assertIn(
                'Complete List of Resources',
                [header.text for header in h3_headers])

        self.assertTrue(self.check_exists_by_id('main_table'))
        self.assertTrue(self.check_exists_by_id('searchDiv'))

        self.assertTrue(self.check_exists_by_class_name('tablesorter'))
```

Thanks!

---

### UPDATE

So per Alex's suggestion below and [this South doc](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings.html#south-tests-migrate), I added this line to my settings.py:

```
SOUTH_TESTS_MIGRATE = False
```

But I am now getting 8 of 8 Errors (before I was getting 1 pass/fail on the first test, and then 7 Errors). The full error for a single test is below:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_table_sorts_on_click (functional_tests.tests.main_resources.Resources)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/<PATH TO VIRTUAL ENV>/virtual_environments/relate/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 259, in __call__
self._pre_setup()
  File "/<PATH TO VIRTUAL ENV>/virtual_environments/relate/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 479, in _pre_setup
self._fixture_setup()
  File "/<PATH TO VIRTUAL ENV>/virtual_environments/relate/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 518, in _fixture_setup
**{'verbosity': 0, 'database': db_name, 'skip_validation': True})
  File "/<PATH TO VIRTUAL ENV>/virtual_environments/relate/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 161, in call_command
return klass.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "/<PATH TO VIRTUAL ENV>/virtual_environments/relate/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 255, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/<PATH TO VIRTUAL ENV>/virtual_environments/relate/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 193, in handle
obj.save(using=using)
  File "/<PATH TO VIRTUAL ENV>/virtual_environments/relate/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/base.py", line 165, in save
models.Model.save_base(self.object, using=using, raw=True)
  File "/<PATH TO VIRTUAL ENV>/virtual_environments/relate/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 626, in save_base
rows = manager.using(using).filter(pk=pk_val)._update(values)
  File "/<PATH TO VIRTUAL ENV>/virtual_environments/relate/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 605, in _update
return query.get_compiler(self.db).execute_sql(None)
  File "/<PATH TO VIRTUAL ENV>/virtual_environments/relate/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1014, in execute_sql
cursor = super(SQLUpdateCompiler, self).execute_sql(result_type)
  File "/<PATH TO VIRTUAL ENV>/virtual_environments/relate/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 840, in execute_sql
cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/<PATH TO VIRTUAL ENV>/virtual_environments/relate/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 122, in execute
six.reraise(utils.IntegrityError, utils.IntegrityError(*tuple(e.args)), sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/<PATH TO VIRTUAL ENV>/virtual_environments/relate/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 120, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/<PATH TO VIRTUAL ENV>/virtual_environments/relate/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 201, in execute
self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/<PATH TO VIRTUAL ENV>/virtual_environments/relate/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
raise errorclass, errorvalue
IntegrityError: Problem installing fixture '/<PATH TO PROJECT>/RDB/fixtures/toy_course.json': Could not load contenttypes.ContentType(pk=8): (1062, "Duplicate entry 'south-migrationhistory' for key 'app_label'")
```

The command I ran:

```
$ python manage.py test functional_tests
```

I'm not quite sure if I made the problem better, worse, or the same, but I seem to be more in-line with the documentation...

Thanks!

---

### UPDATE #2 -- with solution

So a couple of other pages that helped me figure it out (in addition to Alex's pointer to the South doc). First, [this person had a similar issue](http://lduros.net/posts/django-testing-and-south-migrations/), and solved it using the SOUTH_TESTS_MIGRATE = False statement. So half my solution was to include that.

The second half of my solution was to fix my fixture document. I was dumping **everything** into my fixture with:

```
$ python manage.py datadump > RDB/fixtures/toy-course.json
```

This is, apparently, a bad way to do fixtures it with South--because it also dumps the South migration tables into the fixture. The post above shows the blogger using app-specific fixtures (which are also talked about in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113096/django-dump-data-for-a-single-model)), and that was the key to getting my fixtures to work. [The Django docs on fixtures](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-dumpdata) do show the optional parameters to dump just an app, but I didn't know ignoring them would cause South to conflict. So the second half of my solution was to create my fixture to be app-specific:

```
$ python manage.py datadump RDB > RDB/fixtures/toy-course.json
```

And my tests now run fine (slow, but probably a different issue)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test database is created using South migrations by default. Set `SOUTH_TESTS_MIGRATE = False` in your `settings.py`, quote from [docs](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings.html#south-tests-migrate):

> If this is False, South’s test runner integration will make the test
>   database be created using syncdb, rather than via migrations (the
>   default).

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for your answer. I totally missed that doc page...but when I added that into my settings.py, I now get 8 of 8 errors when I run $python manage.py test functional_tests (instead of 1 pass/fail + 7 errors). Same error as above...I will put more details in an update to the question. Am I missing something else? I will do more research, too. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Totally giving the credit to Alex, because he pointed me in the right direction. I figured it out--full answer in my second update.